# Display changing's value in real time (Angular, JS, OOP)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, Right now I'm practicing JS/OOP/Angular via creating some kind of light-text-browser-game :) Got stuck in the simple situation (like always). I simplify my code a bit, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/gjgjc3fx/1/. So I've just created a 'class' Hero using factory:

```
angular.module('myGame', [])
  .factory('Hero', function() {
    function Hero(name, damage) {
      this.name = name;
      this.damage = damage;
    }
    Hero.prototype = {
      talk : function() {
        alert('Hi, my name is: ' + this.name + ', my current damage is: ' + this.damage);
    },
      addDamage : function(damage) {
        this.damage += damage;
        console.log(this.damage);
      }
    }

    return Hero;
  })
```

and then use it in controller:

```
  .controller('myGameCtrl', function($scope, Hero) {
    var am = new Hero('AntiMage', 70);

    $scope.currentDamage = am.damage;
    $scope.hi = function() {
      am.talk();
    }
    $scope.add50Dmg = function() {
      am.addDamage(50);
    }
   })
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='myGame' ng-controller='myGameCtrl'>
  <div>{{currentDamage}}</div>
  <button ng-click='add50Dmg()'>Add 50 damage</button>
  <div ng-click='hi()'>Hi</div>
</div>
```

The question is - what am I suppose to fix if I wanna see in the `<div>{{currentDamage}}</div>` changing damage in real time? I mean if I click on button it will add 50 damage and I can see change in alert's window, but the `<div>{{currentDamage}}</div>` stay the same (70) all the way. Any help and advices will be great.

Comment: you update your `am.demage`, but this value is not pass to `$scope.currentDemage` hence its display 70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjgjc3fx/3/)

The problem is you are not updating `$scope.currentDemage`. For updating `$scope.currentDemage` you have to get the valuee from your `Hero` Factory.

Add `getDamage` function in your factory like

```
Hero.prototype = {
    talk : function() {
    alert('Hi, my name is: ' + this.name + ', my current damage is: ' + this.damage);
  },
  addDamage : function(damage) {
    this.damage += damage;
    console.log(this.damage);
  },

  /* getDamage function */
  getDamage : function(){
      return this.damage;
  }
}
```

Assign your factory instance to `$scope` variable in ngController like

```
 $scope.myService = am;

// watch getDamage() function for binding new Value.
$scope.$watch('myService.getDamage()',function(newvalue){
    $scope.currentDamage = newvalue;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

So there's already two answers and yes, they'll be working.

But I'd like to show you how to make a **reactive** version of it (like you'd do with Angular2 for example).

First of all, here's a working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VK9molLB2UB9BXe9KowX?p=preview) of your code.

**EDIT :** I updated the Plunkr to show you how to use `component` instead of `controller` and I created multiple instance of the game so you can see that it's well synchronized ;) !

---

**Explanations :**

**Define the app**

```
let app = angular.module('myGame', []);
```

**Define `Heroes` factory**

```
app.factory('Heroes', function() {
  // ---------------------------------------------
  // ---------------- observable -----------------
  // ---------------------------------------------
  let heroesFactoryObserver;

  let heroesFactory$ = new Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    heroesFactoryObserver = observer;
  })
  .share();

  // data to subscribe from controller
  let data = {};

  // ---------------------------------------------
  // ------------------- Hero --------------------
  // ---------------------------------------------
  let heroId = 0;

  let Hero = function(name, damage) {
    this.id = heroId++;
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;

    this.hi = () => {
      alert('Hi, my name is: ' + this.name + ', my current damage is: ' + this.damage);
    };

    // default damage : 10
    this.addDamage = (damage = 10) => {
      this.damage += damage;
      heroesFactoryObserver.next(data);
    };
  };

  // ---------------------------------------------
  // -------------- Data to share ----------------
  // ---------------------------------------------
  data = {
    // the observable to subscribe to data change
    heroesFactory$,

    // whenever you need to force update, for example when
    // the app is loaded and you want to get data for the first time
    update: () => heroesFactoryObserver.next(data),

    // your array of heroes
    heroes: [],

    // create a new hero and add him to heroes array
    createHero: (name, damage) => data.heroes.push(new Hero(name, damage))
  };

  return data;
});
```

**Define the `controller`**

```
app.controller('myGameCtrl', function($scope, Heroes) {
  // whenever a heroe his updated
  Heroes.heroesFactory$.subscribe(h => {
    $scope.heroes = h.heroes;
  });

  // load data once by asking Heroes to trigger a change
  // so that every other component can update too
  Heroes.update();
});
```

It's more verbose for sure. But has it forces you to use setters (so you can trigger `observer.next()`), you can use that as hooks and do what you want here. Plus, instead of using angular watch and have the logic within a watch (that you'll need to duplicate for each component where you want to watch the data), you have one source by factory.

---

If you want to push that further, you should learn Redux and how to handle data from a **single source of truth**. Then you might use [ng-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux).

And the best setup I've ever tried is Redux + RxJs. (and I've read that it's possible to use [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store) with AngularJs, not only Angular2).

Comment: Thank you 2, nice solution, my mate also trying to persuade me to learn React/Angular2, but now I'm learning (and actually working) using Angular(1) so... maybe later :) anyway thx, +1

Comment: You can totally work with rxjs and redux **without** moving from angularJs to angular2 or react ! =) Those are just super good practices that'll simplify your life (after passing the learning curve ...). If you're interested in it, I've made a starter with a friend, that uses webpack, angular (+ components and also router uses components) + redux + rxjs here : https://github.com/maxime1992/web-template-webpack Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

More simple

```js
angular.module('myGame', [])

 .controller('myGameCtrl', function($scope) {
     var vm = $scope ;
        vm.currentdamage = 20;
        
       // currentdamage = 20;
   vm.add50Dmg=function(){
      vm.currentdamage = vm.currentdamage +50;
      };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myGame' ng-controller='myGameCtrl'>
  <div>tst {{currentdamage}}</div>
  <button ng-click='add50Dmg()'>Add 50 damage</button>
  <div ng-click='hi()'>Hi</div>
</div>
```